# GCM send message from XML with PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, google-cloud-messaging, message

I need to send a message created from an xml file.

I received such data:
HTTP REQUEST:
POST https: //xxx.xx:xxx
The subject is already included in this link.
And I also have a json key file.

How to do it in PHP?

I did not deal with it, I would be grateful for tips or links to some good training materials.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/CodeMonkeysRu/GCMMessage) regarding Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) PHP Server Library. If you're also encountering an error, there might be a problem with your API key. See these links for additional references: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022592/how-to-send-a-gcm-message-in-php-without-using-curl) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging).

It is also recommended to migrate from GCM to FCM as seen in this [post](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq).

> As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to learn more.